# Pass data between functions in same controller using another service to get data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I get some data through Myservice from another Controller. I can see `{{users.data}}` from the view, but `users.length = 0` ,and `$data` is empty, that means I can't access to the content of MyService in getData function.. if i replace MyService with json data like 
`$scope.users=[{..},{..}]` it works fine 
thank you ..

```
   app.service('MyService', function() {
  return data = [];
  });
  app.controller('tableController', function ($scope, 
   $filter,NgTableParams,MyService) {
        $scope.users= MyService
  $scope.usersTable = new NgTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 6
            }, {
                getData: function(params) {

                    params.total($scope.users.length);
                    $scope.da = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')
    ($scope.users, params.orderBy()) : $scope.da;
                    $scope.da= params.filter() ? $filter('filter')
   ($scope.da, params.filter()) : $scope.users;
                    return $scope.da.slice((params.page() - 1) * 
  params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get your data in the first controller you call `MyService.setData(data);`  The service will store in its local var `data` and keep it there.  Then in the second controller you can retrieve that data by calling `MyService.getData()`

```
app.service('MyService', function() {

    var ret =  {
        data: [],
        setData: function(inData) {
            ret.data = inData;
        },
        getData: function() {
            return ret.data;
        }
    };
    return ret;
});
```

the first controller 1

```
app.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', 'EventService', 'MyService',

    function ($scope, EventService , MyService) {

        var baseUrl = '';

        $scope.getEvents=function()
        {
            var apiRoute = 'http://localhost:9811/notification/notification/';
            var _Event = EventService.getAll(apiRoute);
            _Event.then(function (response) {
                    $scope.events= response.data;
                    MyService.data = $scope.events;
                    MyService.setData($scope.events);
                    $scope.VarCtrl1= MyService;

                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });

        }
        $scope.getEvents()
    }]);
```

i updated the service but it doesnt work ..so i modified the first controller like this what do you think?

```
app.controller('EventCtrl', ['$scope', 'EventService', 'MyService',

  function ($scope, EventService , MyService) {

    var baseUrl = '';

    $scope.getEvents=function()
    {
        var apiRoute = 
   'http://localhost:9811/notification/notification/';
        var _Event = EventService.getAll(apiRoute);
        _Event.then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data
                MyService.setData(data);
                $scope.VarCtrl1= MyService;

            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Error: " + error);
            });

    }
    $scope.getEvents()
}]);
```

Thanks for the update of the service now its better ...i can have data in $users and $data in tableController but orderBy need an array but i get this :(  when i do consoleLoge($scope.users)
       Object {data: Array(0), setData: function, getData: function}data: 
       Array(9)0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: 
       Object7: Object8: Objectlength: 9__proto__: Array(0)getData: 
       function ()setData: function (inData)**proto**: Object
       tableController.js:24

Comment: The first Controller @Jarek kullikowski

Comment: In `EventCtrl` you can remove the line `MyService.data = $scope.events` and in `TableController` you should be able to get data with `$scope.users= MyService.getData()`.  Does this make sense?

Comment: in this case :ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at EventCtrl.js:32
    at processQueue (angular.js:16170)

Comment: Ok, in that case let me change the service a bit, to see if that will get fixed. Give me 2 mins

Comment: now after the last chang in theres ni javascripts error ..but i get no data in users

Comment: I guess you will have to trace it. Maybe put `console.log()` inside `MyService.setData()` and `MyService.getData()` to see if they are being called and with what data.

Comment: why i write MyService.data in the second controller it tells me data undefined ....why ?

Comment: `MyService.setData( data )` sets data in the `MyService` object,  you must be calling `MyService.setData( data )` with `data === undefined` somewhere.